# Какую связь между моделями выбрать?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Имеется модель, назовем её `Landing`, а также модель `Template`
Я хочу, чтобы `Landing` мог иметь связь один-к-одному с моделью `Template`, а `Template`, в свою очередь, имел связь один-ко-многим. Т.е. `Landing` может иметь один `Template`, а один и тот же`Template` может быть закреплен за несколькими `Landing`

`has_one :through` - отлично, но мне не нужна промежуточная модель. Напрашивается связь через соединительную таблицу. `has_and_belongs_to_many` - тоже хорошо, но не то что мне нужно, т.к. `Landing` должен иметь связь один-к-одному, а не один-ко-многим.

Что посоветуете господа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я просто алень. Обычная связь же ))

```
Template
  has_many :landings

Landing
  belongs_to :template
```

Comment: Ну, **бывают** случаи, когда промежуточная связь может быть полезна (в общем случае, как для любых связей 1-к-1, которые технически можно свести в одну сущность), но это тоже рабочий вариант :)